# NTLM for Flask / IIS / SqlAlchemy

Tags: windows, flask, sqlalchemy, iis-7.5, ntlm

I am trying to get a flask app deployed to a windows server (IIS 7.5) that passes the client NTLM Windows Authentication to the SQL Server connection in SQL Alchemy.

At the moment the connections string looks like this:
`"DRIVER={SQL Server Native Client 11.0};Server=%s;Database=%s;TDS_Version=8.0;Trusted_Connection=yes;"`

And the `Trusted_Connection=yes` serves to pass the owner of the web server process to SQL Server. This works great when running the development server because I am invoking the server so my access credentials get passed. **BUT** when IIS runs the server it inherits the application pool identity and sends a bogus non domain user as the auth credentials.

I have tried to use the WindowsAuth setting in the webconfig but SQLAlchemy keeps passing the app pool identity to the sql server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've had similar issues with SQL DB Connections, and the workaround that worked was to create a Windows Network User and have IIS run applications with that identity instead of the App Pool identity. This 'real user' identity is then passed on to any downstream invocations (SQL).

This scales well in an enterprise environment and prevents most security change problems because the user is a 'normal user' and only nominally a 'service account'.